# Selenium IDE value should increase by 1 till 200

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have selenium IDE test case like this

```
    clickAndWait          //area[3
    type                  id=viewbase     14d000001
    type                  id=dob_dd       1
    type                  id=dob_mm       1
    type                  id=dob_yy       1990
    clickAndWait          name=Button
```

i want to make this test case run for 200 times. For each next run,value 14d000001 should increase by 1
for e.g. 14d000002,14d000003 and so on.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need this plugin installed to do a while loop (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/)

This will give you access to a while loop.

The code should be something like

`store 1 Count`

```
while ${Count} < 201
```

clickAndWait          //area[3

type                  id=viewbase     ${Count}

type                  id=dob_dd       1

type                  id=dob_mm       1

type                  id=dob_yy       1990

clickAndWait          name=Button

storeEval             new Number(storedVars['Count']) + 1     Count

endWhile

That will loop through 200 times inputting the number into the id=Viewbase.  If you have to have it in that "14d000001" format, you can concatenate the Count to "14d" with leading zeros.  if it doesn't matter, just as long as there's it goes to 200, you can leave it as is.